# Getting java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: General SSLEngine problem when using Talend with Autonomous Data Warehouse

Tags: oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

I connected Talend to Autonomous Data Warehouse following the instructions supplied by Oracle, https://www.oracle.com/a/ocom/docs/database/talend-connection-adw.pdf

The connection seems to be successful, the studio builder is able to connect and run queries. But when we try to create a new job and add the connection, running the job returns the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: General SSLEngine problem, connect lapse 22 ms., Authentication lapse 0 ms.
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:794)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:688)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:39)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:691)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
at adw.test_0_1.test.tDBInput_1Process(test.java:337)
at adw.test_0_1.test.runJobInTOS(test.java:674)  I ...
```

Anyone has ever seen this before?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem with older jdbc drivers.

Download the latest ojdbc8.jar from https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html is the best way to go.
(I cannot tell you offhand which version it started to work with and where exactly the problem was coming from, but it works with 19.10 and onwards for sure.)